# ¿como hago para la condicion repita un N de veces las otras condiciones python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

como hago para que la ultima condicion de mi script repita las otras condiciones un N de veces que le pase. Todas estas condiciones se llaman en la terminal por el modulo sys como se muestra en el codigo

```
class Automatizar():

    def escribir(self):

        parametros =  sys.argv
        lo_parametros = len(sys.argv)

        for x in range(len(parametros)): parametros[x] = parametros[x]

        for e in range(0, lo_parametros):

            if parametros[e] == "-w":
                .........................

            elif parametros[e] == "-w+":
                .........................

            elif parametros[e] == "-s":
                .........................

            elif parametros[e] == "-l":
                .........................

# Esta condicion debe repetir las demas condiciones

            elif parametros[e] == "-r":
                for parametros in range(int(parametros[e+1])):
                    pass


a = Automatizar()
a.escribir()
```

Lo intente de esta manera pero me crea un bucle infinito.

```
        elif parametros[e] == "-r":
                for parametros in range(int(parametros[e+1])):
                    a.escribir()
```

De esta otra manera cree eun metodo, sin embargo si no le paso el numero de igual manera se ejecutara.

```
def bucle(self):
    repetir = 1 # le pongo 1 se repite 2 veces
    for r in range(repetir):
        a.escribir()
```

Comment: Creo que sería bueno dar ejemplos representativos de entrada y salida esperada. Es ambiguo "Repetir las demás condiciones" , porque las condiciones están aplicadas a parametros[e]. ¿Si se le pasa -r -w -s debe de entrar a la última condición y repetir las condiciones para -w -s ó para -r -w -s? Si es lo último, estás creando un bucle infinito. Si es lo primero, nota que si quitaras la condición -r, entraría a las condiciones de -w y -s.

Comment: Tienes razón, si repito las condiciones que paso por la terminal de igual manera se repetirá la condición -r ya que todo esta junto,  y se repetirá infinitas veces. De manera que ya que es una clase me fui por el lado de crear un método separado que repita el método donde se encuentran las condiciones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haciendolo recursivo, creo que podría quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
class Automatizar(object):

    def escribir(self):
        import sys 
        parametros = sys.argv
        self.bucle(parametros)

    def bucle(self, parametros):
        len_parametros = len(parametros)
        for e in range(0, len_parametros):

            result = self.checkConditions(parametros[e])

            if (not result and parametros[e] == "-r"):
                if(len_parametros <= e+1):
                    print('-r es el último parámetro')
                else:
                    self.bucle(parametros[e+1:])
                    return

    def checkConditions(self, parametro):
        result = True

        if parametro == "-w":
            print('w')

        elif parametro == "-w+":
            print('w+')

        elif parametro == "-s":
            print('s')

        elif parametro == "-l":
            print('l')
        else:
            result = False

        return result

a = Automatizar()
a.escribir()
```

Sin embargo, y a falta de más información, no veo veo la diferencia a implementarlo dejando todas las condiciones:

```
class Automatizar(object):

    def escribir(self):
        import sys 
        parametros = sys.argv
        self.bucle(parametros)

    def bucle(self, parametros):
        len_parametros = len(parametros)
        for e in range(0, len_parametros):
            if parametros[e] == "-w":
                print('w')

            elif parametros[e] == "-w+":
                print('w+')

            elif parametros[e] == "-s":
                print('s')

            elif parametros[e] == "-l":
                print('l')

            elif parametros[e] == "-r":
                continue

a = Automatizar()
a.escribir()
```

En ambos casos

```
-r -w -l imprime -w -l
```

```
 -r -w -r -l imprime -w -l
```

Comment: Bien, gracias por tu respuesta, lo que pasa es que ala hora de ingresar mi código ala pregunta me daba errores de demasiado código ya que tiene muchas condiciones. Gracias